# Passing complex types to a GET operation

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, get

I use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to comunicate with my `Web Api`. But now I have the problem to pass a complex type with a GET method.

With POST I can do it like

```
Dim Client As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
Client.PostAsJsonAsync(Me.BaseUrl & "/api/my", new With { .Id = 5, ... })
```

Is there a similar possibility to do it with GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd question whether `GET` is the right verb here considering you need to pass a complex type, it sounds like it would be better served as a `POST`.

However, if you *have* to use a `GET` then you can either

- Embed the parameters in the URL e.g. `/api/my?field1=1&field2=2&field3=3...`
- Embed the data in a cookie / custom header

Comment: To do it as `POST` seems for me not to be the right way. The multiple parameters are to static. However I will do it than as `POST`. Thanks.